# Change position of Start Menu in Windows 10 when Taskbar is on left edge

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, start-menu

I am currently experimenting with stacked dual-monitor setup, and I find it most convenient when my taskbar is positioned on the left edge of the screen. However, in this case the start menu appears in the top-left corner. Is it possible to somehow move it to the bottom-left?

desired effect:
[image: desired effect]

Comment: Not natively.  You would need to try one on the numerous third party Start Menu replacements.  This functionality is gone altogether in Windows 11.